# Importing color styling in react-native component not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have inherited some react-native code where some styling that apparently used to work is no longer working. This is the line of code in question:

```
<View style={componentStyles.rightButtonContainer}>
```

The styling assigned looks like this:

```
  rightButtonContainer: {
    backgroundColor: config.defaultStyles.greenGradient,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderBottomRightRadius: 25,
    borderTopRightRadius: 25,
    width: "45%",
    height: 50,
    marginLeft: 2,
  }
```

What's not working is the `backgroundColor`. Notice it is using `config.defaultStyles.greenGradient`. Now, the `config` referred to here looks like this:

```
import colors from '../../styles/Colors';
export default {
  defaultStyles: {
    greenGradient: colors.greenGradient,
  }
};
```

The above in turn imports `colors`, which looks like this:

```
export default {
  primary: 'rgb(61, 77, 138)', 
  secondary: 'rgb(20,169,53)', 
  greenGradient: ['rgba(20,169,53,1)', 'rgba(20,169,53,1)', 'rgba(20,169,53,1)', 'rgba(20,159,53,1)', 'rgba(20,159,53,1)'],
  yellowGradient: ['rgba(229,169,42,1)', 'rgba(229,169,42,1)', 'rgba(229,169,42,1)', 'rgba(219,159,42,1)', 'rgba(219,159,42,1)'],
  background: '#fff', 
  indicator: 'rgb(220, 160, 42)', 
  text: '#333',
  textInverse: '#fff',
  textPlaceholder: '#9ab',
  textPlaceholderLight: '#ccc', 
  border:'',
  borderLight: '#ccc', 
};
```

So, it should be ultimately assigning the `greenGradient` color from `colors`, but as I say it's not working. In other words, the green colored button does not render to the screen.

NOTE: this likely stopped working after updating some libraries and the underlying Expo package. Did something change in terms of how styling is handled?

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

React-native doesn't support gradient. You need to use a third-party module like react-native-linear-gradient.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-linear-gradient

Comment: Thanks. Did they support it at one point, and then stop? I ask because this must have been working at some point and then stopped.

Comment: Interestingly, the gradient is working for other parts of the same app. So it must be something about the way it's being imported here.

Comment: In this case, I think this module is already integrated into your project. Please take a look at the package.json.